# How to create one codeigniter menu?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I'm creating a website with CodeIgniter, and It would be great, if I just could edit for example one config file in which I have specified all the menu, and it would edit it for all view files.

So basically in simple OOP i would do this just with a function, but what is the best way to do it in CodeIgniter? Should I use Helper for that?

Comment: What have you tried? There is no *best way to create a menu in CI* - CI is just a framework which doesn't know you need a menu for your application. This question is not constructive. Vote to close.

Comment: Well, currently I'm about to create it with helper, but I'm just asking if there is any better way to do it, that would be more proper for that.

Comment: You should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for questions you shouldn't ask. "*Is there a better way...*" is an open question and therefore not constructive.

Comment: Most straight forward approach is to load a view file. "What you should do" is totally up to you. I am also voting to close based on not enough information, no effort, and no specific concerns or questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head so bear with me if any syntax errors.

In your main controller use this:

```
$template['menu'] = $this->load->view('main/menu', '', TRUE);
$this->load->view('main', $template);
```

You can then use $menu in your main template.

Comment: You can set the 3rd argument as true `$this->load->view('main/menu','',TRUE)` to return the content of the view and assign it to the var